# How to run a joins query which conditionally uses the joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following schema:

```
Freelancers
===========
Id
```

---

```
Availabilities
===========
Date
available (bool)
freelancer_id
```

---

```
GeneralAvailabilities
===========
Date
available (bool)
freelancer_id
```

---

I'm looking to get all freelancers that are available on a given date. A freelancer is available if any of the following are true

1. They have no `Availability` or `GeneralAvailability` on that date
2. They have a `GeneralAvailability` on that date which has `available` set to true
3. They have an `Availability` on that date which has `available` set to true.

In the case that they have an `Availability` set to false but a `GeneralAvailability` set to true, the freelancer is available if the `availabile` value for `Availability` is set to true.

In other words, to see if a freelancer is available on a given date, check the boolean value of `Availability` for that date, if there is no `Availability` for that date check the boolean value of `GeneralAvailability` for that date. If there is no `Availability` or `GeneralAvailability` for that date then they are available by default.

The SQL WHERE statement i have so far is as follows:

```
WHERE (
  ( availabilities.id IS NULL )
  OR NOT (
    availabilities.date = ?
    AND
    availabilities.available = false
  )
) OR (
  ( general_availabilities.id IS NULL )
  OR NOT (
    general_availabilities.weekday = ?
    AND
    general_availabilities.available = false
  )
)
```

This works for most cases except when there is an `Availability` that is false and a `GeneralAvailability` that is true. The freelancer should not be returned in that case, as the `Availability` should supercede the `GeneralAvailability` and only fall back on the `GeneralAvailability` if there is no `Availability` for that date.

Hopefully that makes sense! Thanks so much for taking the time to have a look at my question.

Josh

Comment: Pls compile a "truth table" to help you (and us) define all the conditions and output required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left join onto the availability tables using the date, and then just filter based on "no successful join" before "has a true"

```
select
    freelancers.id
from
    freelancers
    left join availabilities on(
        availabilities.freelancer_id = freelancers.id
        and availabilities.date = '2017.09.28'::date
    )
    left join general_availabilities on(
        general_availabilities.freelancer_id = freelancers.id
        and general_availabilities.date = '2017.09.28'::date
    )
where
    (
        availabilities is null
        and general_availabilities is null
    )
    or availabilities.available = true
    or (
        availabilities is null
        and general_availabilities.available = true
    )
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will return freelancers which have `availabilities` set to `FALSE` and `general_availabilities` set to `TRUE`. The `general_availability` should always be superseded to whatever the `availability` is set to

Comment: @JoshuaHarris Ah yes, missed that bit. I have updated the query

Comment: Thanks so much, all sorted now!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should provide some sample of your dataset. But I sense from your logic that the OR is wrong. 
Maybe something like this works better?

```
WHERE (
  ( availabilities.id IS NULL )
  AND NOT (
    availabilities.date = ?
    AND
    availabilities.available = false
  )
) OR (
  ( general_availabilities.id IS NULL )
  AND NOT (
    general_availabilities.weekday = ?
    AND
    general_availabilities.available = false
  )
)
```

Otherwise I think you should give some sample data to demonstrate your example.

Comment: Thanks for your help! scoots got me where I needed to go but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze multiple conditions, can be useful a "table" like this, called "truth table".

As far as I understood your question, it can be:

```
+---+-----------------+----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|   | TAB.            |                | TAB. GENERAL                |                |        OUTPUT         |
|   | AVAILABILITIES  |                |   AVAILABILITIES            |                |                       |
+---+-----------------+----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
|   | DATE            | flag AVAILABLE | DATE                        | flag AVAILABLE | Free lancer Available |
| 1 | present         | F              | present                     | F              | F                     |
| 2 | present         | F              | not present                 | --             | T                     |
| 3 | present         | F              | present                     | T              | F                     |
| 4 | present         | T              | present                     | F              | T                     |
| 5 | present         | T              | not present                 | --             | T                     |
| 6 | present         | T              | present                     | T              | T                     |
| 7 | not present     | --             | present                     | F              | T                     |
| 8 | not present     | --             | not present                 | --             | T                     |
| 9 | not present     | --             | present                     | T              | T                     |
+---+-----------------+----------------+-----------------------------+----------------+-----------------------+
```

Using it, it can be quite simple to write conditions for your query (if you amend above truth table, we can change WHERE condition following) to select available freelancer for a given date (xxx is your date; I shorten for simpleness some fields and tables name but I think you can see it):

```
SELECT A.ID
FROM FREELANCER A
LEFT JOIN AVAILAB B ON A.ID = B.FREEL_ID AND B.DATE = xxx
LEFT JON GENERAL_AVAILAB C ON A.ID = C.FREEL_ID AND C.DATE = xxx
WHERE  B.AVAILABLE IS NULL OR B.AVAILABLE = TRUE  OR C.AVAILABLE IS NULL
```

If you post sample data or tell me conditions I can test/change the query.

Comment: Thanks for your help! scoots got me where I needed to go but I appreciate your help.